# What's the purpose of putting properties without assigning a value?

Tags: javascript

I see in some code things like this:

```
var MyObject = function (options) {
    this.variableOne;
    this.variableTwo;
};
```

Properties are put without assigning any values to them. I find it's done intentionally, but I have no idea why it's done.

Can you please explain me the purpose of this technique?

Comment: FWIW, added a note to my answer. Could be related to tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the language perspective, there is none whatsoever.<sup>1</sup> That's just something people new to JavaScript do to "declare" instance properties. It has no effect at all. Beat the author about the head and shoulders with a wet noodle.

It's possible that some *tools* (like an IDE) may pick that up and use it to feed into their auto-completion feature, e.g., that a tool may see that access and say "Ah, okay, so this thing has a `variableOne`, I'll remember that and offer it as a completion suggestion." I'd suggest that if you're going to do that, providing a default value for the property as well would make the intent clearer, but that's a matter of style.

---

<sup>1</sup> ...assuming that `variableOne` and `variableTwo` aren't defined with getters with side effects on the prototype. If they *are* defined with getters with side effects on the prototype, replace the wet noodle with something with more heft.

As there's a comment asking them, here's more about getters with side effects (in comments):

```js
// Using class syntax for brevity, but transpiling is enabled so
// it'll work even if your browser doesn't support them yet

// Here, we have a property on the prototype with a getter.
// This is absolutely fine and normal.
class Person {
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }
  // The getter
  get fullName() {
    return (this.first + " " + this.last).trim();
  }
}
const joe = new Person("Joe", "Bloggs");
console.log(joe.fullName); // "Joe Bloggs"

// Here, we have a property on the prototype with a getter
// *with side effects*. This is a Bad Thing™.
class Thingy {
  constructor(info) {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.info = info;
  }
  // The getter with side effects. It should be a method,
  // not a getter. Getters shouldn't have side effects.
  get something() {
    ++this.counter;
    return this.info;
  }
}
const t = new Thingy("foo");
console.log(t.something, t.counter); // foo 1
console.log(t.something, t.counter); // foo 2 -- ?!?! What changed counter?!

// Here, we have a property on the prototype with a getter
// with side effects where the constructor relies on the side
// effect. This is a Very Bad Thing™. Side effects are bad
// enough, but side effects of hidden operations (a getter is
// a hidden method call) are a maintenance nightmare.
class Wrong {
  constructor() {
    this.magic;
  }
  // The getter with side effects
  get magic() {
    this.nowWeAreReallyInitialized = true;
    return "magic";
  }
  doSomething() {
    if (!this.nowWeAreReallyInitialized) {
      throw new Error("We're aren't initialized!");
    }
    console.log("Doing something");
  }
}
const w = new Wrong();
// The only reason doSomething works is that the property accessor
// for `magic` was accessed from the constructor. This is wrong.
// Wrong wrong wrong. :-)
w.doSomething();
```

Comment: Why is it bad to define them with getters? What if the objects are not meant to be declared if they are never used?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin: Defining properties with getters is not bad. Defining properties with getters *with side effects* is bad. Doing that and then relying on calling those getters with side effects from the constructor by doing an apparently do-nothing property access in it is *really* bad.

Comment: I can't get the image of wet noodle assault and battery out of my head ... btw, is "really bad" ™ as well or is that reserved for *Very Bad Thing™* :p

Answer (score 1):

This way they call getters. Maybe the getters do some initialization the first time they are called, and it's important to do that work in the constructor.

```js
var MyObject = function (options) {
    this.variable;
};
Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, 'variable', {
  get: function() {
    console.log('Getter called');
  }
});
new MyObject();
```

Comment: Heh, I'd just added a note about getters to my answer a few moments before you posted this. :-)

Comment: `and it's important to do that work in the constructor` - of course, if that's the case, then the work should be done **in the constructor** :p